# In MySQL, if has many-to-many table, should i create auto-incr column as PK or use multi-column unique as PK? and Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

for exmaple, has course relationship table, student id and course id is multi-unique, if i create this relationship table, should i use auto-incr column as PK, or use student id and course id as multi-PK ?

Answer (score 0):

Some people add auto-increment column as PK to just every table.

But I believe it is good to have a multi-column-PK in the case where the table is a relationship table between two or more tables.

On the other hand, it is more effort to delete a multi-column-PK table entry, because you need to give all columns in the multi-column-PK.

Also, check whether your technology stack (programming language) has problems with multi-column-PK.

Comment: I use MySQL databse,. If i use multi-column_PK as PK, for Insert operation,  Will it cost more time ? in other word, would it lock more index-record?

Comment: Well you probably would have indexes on the multi-column columns anyway, so adding an artificial PK is just one more index to update on insert.

Answer (score 0):

This is something of a matter of opinion, but I put a synthetic primary key (auto-incremented id) in almost every table I create, including association/junction tables.

Why?  Here are some reasons:

- If I need to delete or update rows, then the primary key simplifies the process and reduces the change for error.
- The primary key captures the insertion order of the rows.
- If the row needs to be referred to by another table, then you can refer to it by a primary key.
- In some databases, the primary key is used to cluster the data (that is, sort the data on the data pages).  An auto-incremented primary key ensures that data goes "at the end".  A natural primary key can result in fragmented data.

As an example of the third point, you might have an `attendance` table that records -- by day -- whether a student attended a class s/he is enrolled in.  This could refer to the enrollment table.

Comment: what's meaning of synthetic primary key? auto-incr PK or multi-column PK ?

Comment: `synthetic primary key` means an `auto-increment PK` which is only used by the database, unlike lets say a key or reference number which is communicated to the user.